# How do I automate share file functionality using XCUItest

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest

My application has ability to preview file which is shared by other application. I want to automate the share file testing using UI testing provided by Xcode.

How do I automate share file functionality using XC UI test in Xcode?

Comment: So you have app1, which has the share button on tapping it, it opens other app2 which takes the file shared by app1?

Comment: My files are kept in Files app in iCloud drive. I want to share it to my application Using XC UI test